# Sum max path algorithm gives unexpected solution

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, graph

in my input `numbers[3][2] == 62` everything ok algorithms works correctly
but `numbers[3][2] == 63` algorithms give me unexpected result I cant understand this reason.
I try to  design algorithm like this you can go only non prime numbers and only walk `root > leftchild` or `root > rightchild`
some example:

```
10
20 23
40 50 60
65  60 69 80
```

`10 +20+50+69 = 149` right one 
`10 +0(23) + 60+80 = 150`  wrong one we can't walk prime !

I have tried to debug nearly all parts of this algorithm but I can't understand problem reason

```py
import sys


numbers = [
       [10],
     [20, 23],
    [40, 50, 60],
  [10, 20, 63, 80]
]


def IsNotPrime(a ): # 
    sayac = 0
    if(a == 0 or a == 1 ):
        sayac = sayac +1
    else:
        for i in range(2,a):
            if(a % i == 0 ):
                sayac = sayac +1
            else:
                sayac = sayac
    if(sayac == 0):
        return False# prime
    else:
        return True # non prime

def bigger(a,b):
    if(a>b ):
        return a
    elif(b>=a ):
        return b


for i in range((len(numbers)-2),-1,-1): 
    for j in range (0,(len(numbers[i]))):
        a = numbers[i][j]#root
        b = numbers[i+1][j]#left chield
        c = numbers[i+1][j+1]#right chield
        if( IsNotPrime(a) and IsNotPrime(b) and IsNotPrime(c) ):
            numbers[i][j] = (a + bigger(b,c))

        elif(IsNotPrime(a) and IsNotPrime(b)):
               numbers[i][j] = (a + b)

        elif( IsNotPrime(a) and IsNotPrime(c) ):
               numbers[i][j] = (a + c)


print( numbers[0][0])
```

code gives result `90` but 
I expect result `143`  `10+20+50+63 = 143` for this case (max sum path can be run only root to peer and  can't walk prime).

Comment: Some advice.  1. Fix the problems you have found (`isprime(a): # change name IsNotPrime`).  2. Try to simplify.  3.  Tell us what you want it to do.

Comment: 1. ım change name of fucntion  2 . ım trying find max path sum on this conditions; walk only non prime numbers, walk only root to peers(only one each time ), walk only up to down 3. Can you describe me why  numbers[3][2] == 62  => result is 142 but numbers[3][2] == 63 => result is 90 ?

Comment: Because 112 is not prime, but 113 *is* prime.

Answer (score 0):

You are not checking the individual numbers to see if they are prime.  You are checking the running total.  50 + 63 = 113 which is prime, so that path is disallowed.